# What do you call someone who’s good, but has a bad reputation?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’ve been trying to find this word for a long time. Essentially, because of the fact that the person I’m writing about is “scary”, they’re perceived to be evil and cruel. In reality, they’re a sweetheart. What’s the word for that? I want to use it but Google keeps giving me words for folks who are actually bad, or “how to avoid gaslighting”.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of our requirements for posts is that they ***show some research.***, as well as a sample sentence demonstrating how the [single word](https://english.stackexchange.com/help)  is to be used.

Comment: The person is misrepresented.

Comment: Yes, of course, a hooker with a heart of gold. Next we ask what's a good girl like you doin' in a place like this?

Comment: I have cast the final vote to re-open your question....please take some time to edit according to the suggestions from other users as well as site guidelines...if you cannot provide a sentence showing usage of the intended language, I will be forced to re-close the Q.

Comment: I would have written "someone who is a *good person*, but has a bad reputation."  I do not usually see the word "good" used in this way (in reference to a person) in the US.

Comment: Google is not a source; it is a search engine.

Comment: Do mean someone well-known who is good in person but has an unfair public reputation for being bad despite their best efforts at being nice (maybe because of bad media reporting); or someone who (more or less deliberately) projects an image of being bad but is secretly good (like a heel wrestler who visits children's hospitals); or someone who looks dodgy at first glance but you soon discover has a heart of gold; or something else?

Answer (score 5):

We might say that this person is...

1. **defamed**. [defame](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defame) (verb): to harm the reputation of by communicating false statements about : to harm the reputation of by libel... or slander...
2. **demonized**. [demonize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demonized) (verb): to portray (someone or something) as evil or as worthy of contempt or blame
3. [**maligned**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maligned) (adjective): spoken about in an injurious way : harshly or unfairly criticized
4. [**misunderstood**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misunderstood) (adjective): 2: not sympathetically appreciated
5. **vilified**. [vilify](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vilify) (transitive verb) 1: to utter slanderous and abusive statements against :
   2: to lower in estimation or importance

Comment: I came here to say 'misunderstood' but all these are good.

Comment: +1 for “misunderstood.”

Comment: With all due respect, none of these express the idea that as well as being perceived badly, the person is actually good. And despite MW, maligned does not have the connotation of unfair.

Comment: @David I'm afraid that rejecting the authority of reference books leaves us in a lurch. But I would agree that describing a particular criticism as false or unfair does not deny that the defamed or maligned person has unrelated faults. Is this your point? I don't think the original request was for a single word that conveyed the complex and unusual idea that someone is completely flawless but mistaken for a scoundrel.

Answer (score -4):

*There’s no single word — you have to use a phrase.*

Here are a few:

> Not as black as he’s painted

Perhaps not politically correct these days, especially as it’s applied to the [devil](https://proverbhunter.com/the-devil-is-not-so-black-as-he-is-painted/), no less. And “not that bad” is not quite equivalent to “good”.

Alternatively, you could say something like:

> Beneath that gruff exterior lies a heart of gold

but it’s a bit hackneyed and it’s impossible to find a reference to it on a Google search because there’s some pop song of the same name.

Then there’s:

> A sheep in wolf’s clothing

which I see has been adopted by [a low-alcohol brewery](https://siwcbrewery.com).

or, clutching at straws

> He’s just had a bad press

And at my side of the Atlantic it would be all right to say:

> She’s really just a pussy cat

but, taking up the sweetheart:

> He comes over as hard-boiled, but really he has a soft centre

and finally (you hope):

> He’s just a chocolate policeman

Don’t bother searching on Google, all you’ll get is people trying to sell you chocolate. And, anyway, I made it up.

Comment: You need more than one word: *not as bad as...*